# How to have my hair cut?

Tags: grammar-choice, modern-life

I am looking for an expression for "I am having my hair cut".
When I have my hair cut, I ask someone to cut my hair, instead of cutting my hair by myself. With **secare** for *to cut*, I think of two constructions:

1. Use a synecdochical accusative:

> Capillos secor.

- It seems a little weird for non-poetic contexts.

2. Use causative **facere ut**:

> Facio ut capilli secentur.
>
> *or*
>
>  Facio ut capillos secet. (with **aliquis** understood)

- It seems a little verbose.

Are there any other options? Are there ancient examples for this?

Comment: Perhaps *tondere* in some construction?

Comment: While @cmw gives the most appropriate answer for the particular case of having one's hair cut, it is worth noting that for more “heavy-weight” examples, like “the emperor had all his enemies crucified,” there are more explicit expressions, in particular *iubere*, e.g. *omnes hostes in crucem figi iussit*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about something more straightforward, from Plautus's [*Asinaria*](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/119/2/6/917-923@1#6):

> Ad tonsorem ire dixit.
> He said he was going to the barber.

But if you're not going to a barber per se, just going to get a haircut (from someone else, someone unknown, perhaps), you can use the passive form of *resecare* with [*capilli*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=resec+%7E+capill) or [*coma*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=coma+%7E+resec), like with *sit coma, sit trita barba resecta* in [Ovid](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=coma+%7E+resect).

To express your desire to *go* get a haircut, you should be able to use a purpose clause, like so:

> eo [somewhere] ut capilli resecentur.
> I am going [somewhere] so that that my hair be cut.

Comment: What's the difference between **secare** and **resecare**? Smith & Hall's dictionary gives "**capillos secare** (Sen.)" in the entry "cut", but I can't find the original text. What nuance does prefix **re-** have? (I also found **rescindere**)

Comment: @KotobaTrilyNgian Smith's isn't clear here, but it's *comas recidere* that Seneca has, which is printed right before *capillum secare*. You can see it [here](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/1017/9/28/992-996,1066-1070,1086-1091@1#28). As far as *secare* v. *resecare*, I imagine the *re-* prefix indicates that the hair is being cut *back*. You can find both in use in the Classical period.